# TFS 2012 Document Hyper-Links

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010

In TFS 2005, from Team Explorer in Visual Studio, we used to be able to very easily view a documents properties and view the hyper-link. We could then copy this and share it in an email, intranet etc. We have recently upgraded to TFS 2012 using Sharepoint 2010 and I cannot seem to locate document hyper-links.

Is there an easy way to obtain these (without knowing the hyperlinks) or is there another easy way to share content stored in the TFS SharePoint document store? I can do it from the SharePoint Portal easy enough, but I don't really use this, I use Team Explorer and the TFS Web Screens mostly

Many Thanks

Comment: Looks like MS "forgot" this nice functionality, as they likes to do in other their products

Answer (score 0):

this question is quite a bit older, but: maybe I've got an idea?

In each work Item, you have a register "All links"
There you can put the hyperlink to your sharepoint document in. (Button "Link to", Link Type "Hyperlink)

We used this since TFS 2010 and I sumbled over this thread, 'cause we are running into an issue, where these linked documents could not be checked out after opening.

Regards
Jimmy

P.S: maybe, I completely misunderstood?

Comment: I think this may be something different. The problem I have is obtaining the hyperlinks. It's not as easy as it was in TFS 2005 where you could just select the document/file in Team Explorer and the hyperlink displays in the properties window. In TFS 2012, it appears not to do that :(